Are there ways to convert Pathfinder Bestiary monsters to Path of War?
I’ve been looking for ways in the books, but it doesn’t seem like there are any. Could someone walk me through how to do this?

Path of War is a supplement (by Dreamscarred Press,¹ a third-party publisher, not Paizo) for Pathfinder 1e. There is no “conversion” here: Path of War is mean to be added onto Pathfinder 1e, not instead of. You want to be thinking about adding Path of War to Bestiary monsters.
The easiest way to add Path of War maneuvers to Bestiary monsters is to have that monster take feats from among Martial Training I-VI, instead of some of their usual feats. Monsters’ non-bonus feats (without the B) are just the usual feats at odd levels, and a creature doesn’t have to have its usual feats in those slots. (Obviously, as GM, you can totally change bonus feats too, it’s just a bit less “expected” by the system.) This is a “normal” adjustment that can be done more-or-less freely; the balancing is built into the feats and the usual odd-level feat progression.²
Much more complicated would be giving monsters their own maneuver progressions. There isn’t—and cannot be—a one-size-fits-all “system” for doing that: at that point, you’re brewing your own variant monster, and that means you’ll have to manually balance it, and ideally test it. There can be some rules of thumb, but ultimately the devil’s in the details and those you’ll have to figure out yourself. As a starting point, CR is (very) roughly analogous to level, so maneuver levels should be at most half that (rounded up). From there, you’ll want to consider what other class features a martial adept with those maneuvers would have, and how those compare to the other things the monster can do. For instance, a dragon probably can’t have the same maneuvers a warden of its CR would: a dragon has a whole lot of advantages beyond what the warden class offers. So a dragon should probably have lower-level maneuvers than a warden would at the same CR. Or start losing some of its dragon-y features to make up for it.

Disclaimer: I did some freelance work for Dreamscarred Press back in the day, but after Path of War was published. I was uninvolved in that work (aside from being friends with some of the people working on it).

Disclaimer: This point—and really this entire answer—is predicated on Pathfinder being balanced. Unfortunately, it is not. Some feats are much stronger, or weaker, than others. And Path of War is relatively high-power compared to much of Pathfinder, so ultimately, replacing a monster’s feats with Martial Training will probably increase its power–possibly by a large amount. Unfortunately, addressing this issue just gets into the “more complicated” scenario discussed in the final paragraph.



How would you add Path of War to monsters that do not qualify for Martial Training?

@RowanHamilton That goes under the “more complicated” approach in the last paragraph. Ultimately, Martial Training’s requirements are usually pretty amenable for monsters—you can qualify just with BAB, note that it’s BAB or Knowledge (martial) ranks, you don’t need the Knowledge if you have the BAB—so usually waiving those requirements is going to mean an increase in the creature’s power which means removing something else to compensate.
